# Counting inversions in C++ via mergesort

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a text file that contains 100,000 numbers from 1 ~ 100,000 in an unsorted manner (no duplicates).

The name of the file is ["IntegerArray.txt"](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qe5dp2a01u88o0/IntegerArray.txt?dl=0)

My task is to count the number of inversions in the text file.  An inversion is a pair of elements `a`, `b` where `a` comes before `b`, but `a > b`.  Thus "1 2 3 6 4 5" contains two inversion (6 > 4 and 6 > 5).

I implemented it with the merge sorting method; the sorting works, but the counting inversions part kept giving out wrong answers, and I cannot find why.

The following is my code:

```
long long mergeAndCount(vector<int>& vec, int p, int q, int r) {
    long long count = 0;

    vector<int> L, R;
    for (int i = p; i <= q; ++i) L.push_back(vec[i]);
    for (int j = q + 1; j <= r; ++j) R.push_back(vec[j]);

    L.push_back(numeric_limits<int>::max()); //sentinel element
    R.push_back(numeric_limits<int>::max());

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (int k = p; k <= r; ++k) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            vec[k] = L[i];
            ++i;
        } else {
            vec[k] = R[j];
            ++j;
            if (L[i] != L.back() && R[j] != R.back())
                // Problem SOLVED: change this line to count += q - p + 1 - i
                count += q - i + 1; 
        }
    }
    return count;
}

long long inversion(vector<int>& vec, int p, int r) {
    long long count = 0;

    if (p < r) {
        int q = (p + r) / 2;
        count = inversion(vec, p, q);
        count += inversion(vec, q + 1, r);
        count += mergeAndCount(vec, p, q, r);
    }

    return count;
} 

int main() {
    ifstream infile("IntegerArray.txt"); 
    int a;
    vector<int> vec;

    while (infile >> a)
        vec.push_back(a);

    cout << inversion(vec, 0, vec.size()-1);
    return 0;
}
```

The result from the above code is 32620796130, which is incorrect.

The answer by brute force with the following code is 2407905288, which is correct.

```
long long inversion(vector<int>& vec, int p, int r) {
    long long count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < vec.size(); ++j)
            if (vec[i] > vec[j])
                ++count;

    return count;
}
```

Can someone help me out solving this?

Comment: What do you call "the number of inversion?" If it's the **minimum** number of inversion needed to get a sorted file/array/list, you won't get it with any standard sorting algorithm.

Comment: What does "Inversions are defined as in an array" mean?

Comment: Could you show input data with say 5 elements, and the expected output, and an explanation of that.

Comment: I made a typo while typing in my comment. Here's the definition.
Inversions are defined as in an array, when the indices i <j, but array[i] > array [j], array[i] and array[j] are inverted pairs.
So basically I think it's the number of swapping that occurs during the sorting process.

Comment: So if the input array is: 
{ 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6 },

(3,2) (5,2) (5,4) 

are the inverted pairs

Comment: Ok, then the answer is 100'000 +/- 1. I'll always be able to sort 100'000 data points in 100'000+/-1 swaps. If you're looking for the **minimal** number of swaps, then you get a real question ;)

Comment: as you can see from the above example, only 3 steps of sorting occur, since it's already partly sorted.

Comment: Really? the answer is 2407905288. 

Isn't the merge sort an O(n log n) algorithm?

Comment: Please could you edit your question to add extra information rather than putting it in comments?

Comment: Can I suggest your run through your failing code in a debugger with the sample list you have just given?

Comment: I could't reproduce the error. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ad6d3d6d2db7296 Output is as expected. I just replaced your counting indexes' type (`int`) by `std::vector<int>::size_type`.

Comment: You don't need to sort in order to apply your algorithm.

Comment: @MartinBonner As you suggested, I ran through my code with { 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6 }, and the resulted output was the answer 3.

Comment: Problem Solved:
I just needed to change "count += q - i + 1;" to "count = count + q - p + 1 - i;"